# Error: There are no opened connections during replay in VUGEN

Tags: loadrunner

I am trying connect Remote desktop server in Loadrunner VUGEN with below code by using RDP protocol

```
rdp_connect_server("Host=fsdgdfgfdgfd112", 
    "UserName=AB\\{RDP_Username}", 
    "EncryptedPassword=fdfd234fdfb", 
    "Domain=", 
    RDP_LAST);
```

getting below error message

```
Test.c(9): Error: There are no opened connections
```

Test.c(9): **There was an error while connecting to the RDP Server

Please let me know what could be the issue

Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have terminal server, you are only going to be able to initiate 1-2 RDP connections per host

By (Microsoft) Design as a limit.